# Parsing multiline logs using pyspark with regexp

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I struggle with pyspark to split a logfile into a dataframe that may contains multiline events. These events is what I need help with.

The log file has the format

```
2020-04-03T14:12:24,368 DEBUG [main] blabla bla bla bla
2020-04-03T14:12:24,371 DEBUG [main] bla bla bla bla 
2020-04-03T14:12:24,348 DEBUG [Thread-2] multiline log line bla bla 
bla bla bla
bla bla
    blablabla
2020-04-03T14:12:24,377 DEBUG [main] blabla bla bla bla
```

To split a single line into groups, I can simply use

```
log_pattern = r'(\d*-\d*-\d*)T(\d*:\d*:\d*,\d*)[ ]{1,}(DEBUG|INFO|WARN|FATAL|ERROR|TRACE)[ ]{1,}(\[.*\])[ ]{1,}(.*)'
logs_df = base_df.select(regexp_extract('value', log_pattern, 1).alias('date'),
                         regexp_extract('value', log_pattern, 2).alias('timestamp'),
                         regexp_extract('value', log_pattern, 3).alias('log_level'),
                         regexp_extract('value', log_pattern, 4).alias('application'),
                         regexp_extract('value', log_pattern, 5).alias('log_content'))
logs_df.show(10, truncate=True)
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
|      date|   timestamp|log_level|application|         log_content|
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
|2020-04-08|00:35:12,014|     INFO|     [main]|Log4J2Helper:68 -...|
|2020-04-08|00:35:12,014|     INFO|     [main]|Log4J2Helper:69 -...|
....
```

What I want is the `log_content` to contain the multiline log event. However, I don't understand how I should be able to split the lines with regards of the multiline comments. I've tried splitting, regexp lookahead but do not seem to get it right.

The `spark.read.tex` seems to have the option of a custom new line delimiter, but it cannot take regexp.

I thought of just parsing using the re module first, but since the log files are the size of gigabyte, I probably run into memory and processing problems.

Can someone direct me how I should handle these large multiline log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture all following lines that do not start with for example 1 or more digits and a hyphen using a negative lookahead in the last group `(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+-).*)*)`

Note that if you use `\d*-\d*-\d*` you could possibly also match `--` as the quantifier `*` matches 0 or more times.

This part `\[.*\]` can be written using a negated character class `\[[^][]*\]` to prevent overmatching and make it a bit more performant.

```
(\d+-\d+-\d+)T(\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)[ ]+(DEBUG|INFO|WARN|FATAL|ERROR|TRACE)[ ]+(\[[^][]*\])[ ]+(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d+-).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x2ZfCV/1)

Comment: It worked very well on the statements I checked, exluding the ```\[[^][]*\]``` and replacing it with what I had before.  Can you explain `the ```\[[^][]*\]``` in more detail?

Do you have any other tips for parsing really big log files into a dataframe?

Comment: This part `[^][]*` is a negated character class, which repeats matching any char except `[` or `]` 0 or more times. If you use `\[.*\]`, it will first match `[`, then it will match until the end of the line using `.*` and will then backtrack until the first occurrence of `]` which could give unexpected results like matching too much. I have no experience with parsing large log files into a dataframe. If using a regex is too slow, you might use the native string functions.

Comment: Thank you. However, the ```\[[^][]*\]``` only works when you have a single character between the brackets. Can you edit so it works for multiple signs?

Comment: @user3061876 Not sure what you mean by that. This part `\[[^][]*\]` will also work if the string to match is `[]`. Can you give an example string where it does not work? You could also open https://regex101.com/r/x2ZfCV/1 and then add the string to the example data. Then you can update the link at the left top of the page where it says `Update Regex` and then share the link in the comment.

Comment: Your regex101 link shows that it is working. I tested it with https://www.regextester.com/ and the same regex with the same input did not work. I will use the regex101 in the future. Thank you for the clarification!